# Auditing and redisplaying user interactions in Angular application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, audit

We are developing an application using Angular 5 in UI. There is a requirement to audit user interactions and to display all filled forms when needed. So if a user filled a form and submitted it, the whole JSON of request be persisted somewhere (in a Mongo-DB perhaps). And in another menu some moderator users can search the audited request and redisplay the form as it was filled by user.

Though back-end is developed using Spring Boot, I was thinking to use a Servlet Filter to audit all JSON REST request. Also I was thinking to `disable` the `FormGroup` object when viewing in audit mode.

But there are some things I don't know how to handle. I want to have two services for each form, one to fetch the data from mongo-db (to view in audit mode)and one to fetch the data from RDBMS in normal form.
Another problem is I want to display the form in audit mode in a modal, and I want to know how to do that, because in this modal form I can not use normal routing. Is it possible without lots of duplicate code or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Backend (SpringBoot app)**: I had a similar requirement (only for the backend though), the way we went about it was by creating an annotation @Auditable and used AOP pointcuts to capture the requests/response of the method the annotation was attached to and then store it in the Audit document(mongodb). We also made it Async so that it doesn't affect the actual response time.

**UI (Angular)**: Yes it is possible without duplicating the code. You need to create two parent components each interacting with different services. 
One for the RDBMS and the other for the Mongodb. 
These parent components will pass the model object to the child component that has the viewing of the form using the [`@Input`](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction). Along with the model object you'll need to pass a boolean for disabling or not. You'll be able to create the `FormGroup` using the model object passed from the parent and also disable it accordingly using the `disable` property on the `FormGroup`.

Not sure which css library you are using but for the Modal, you can easily achieve that using material design, bootstrap, ng2-bootstrap, primeng etc. 
The parent component interacting with MongoDB should simply wrap the child inside the Modal.

Your problem can be solved with many different approaches, above is just one of them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, using `@Auditable` which is a Hibernate/Envers annotation is not so great, because I want to store the audit info regardless of main transaction success or failure. For the second part, the problem is we have many forms in our application (more than 50 forms), and each of them has a different service. Can you describe more how to these two parent components in angular to handle this?

Comment: There is no annotation currently in [Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/) called `@Auditable`, I think you might be confusing it with `@AuditTable`, which is a Class level annotation to define the schema and table name. Anyways the idea was to use AOP to capture the request and response for auditing, you can name the Annotation whatever you like. For the second part do you have a sample code that we can use ? It'll be more easier that ways.

Comment: Sorry the Envers annotation is `@Audited`.